# How to use curl call api

Tags: php, curl

I have 2 domain in server. I assume name : mydomain1 and mydomain2

mydomain2 call api in  mydomain1 and mydomain2 use database in mydomain1

So. In mydomain2 I coding php file as follow:

```
$addLogLogin = "https://mydomain1.com/apis/setLogLogin";
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $addLogLogin);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
```

and. File setLogLogin.php I coding php file as follow :

```
db_connect();
restoreSession();
updateLog($user_id,1);  //+1 number user and stored into database;
```

**operation**
When compile file php in mydomain2. It call api setLogLogin.php in mydomain1. and fetch data user and update log in database

**But**
It don't work for me.It not update Log in database. What is wrong?

Comment: Could you show us the rest of the code from `setLogLogin.php` and post any errors you're displayed? It might be easier for you to write this in your first language. I'm sure someone will be able to translate for you.

Comment: today I find Error by using curl_error

if(curl_exec($c) === false)
 { echo "error : {curl_error}";} 
else {echo "Not error";}

But not have Error and It display "Not error". I don't know about error.